# Re-generate Keys error in the Private App screen

Tags: xero-api

I have create a private app in xero developer and authorized for 'Demo Company (Global)'.  Then, the keys were generated.

However, if I click on 'Regenerate Keys', then there are errors and the dialog box won't go away

Answer (score 0):

I had a look into the errors. Looks like the most likely reason you are getting this error is that you no longer have the Admin role in the Organisation.

You cannot regenerate keys if you don't have access to the Organisation.

Check out https://go.xero.com/Settings/Users for details on what User are part of the Org.

If this is not the case, please raise a ticket with your details: https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support/

Thanks